# How to format Asp.net SMTP Email with HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, smtp

I was doing an SMTP email that will send the order details to the customer email after the purchase. I had successfully sent it to the customer but the format is a little weird.

Below is the output it sends to the customer email.

```
Your order is successful!
------------------------------------------------
Order ID : Order20465230820207quiw< br />Order Date : 8/30/2020< br />Send To : 81,JALAN KENARI MERAH 8
<br />  Kedah< br />  05200< br />Grand Total : 499< br />< br />< br />Thank You for purchasing with us!
```

But it expects it to format like this :

```
Your order is successful!
------------------------------------------------
Order ID : Order20465230820207quiw
Order Date : 8/30/2020
Send To : 81,JALAN KENARI MERAH 8
Grand Total : 499
Thank You for purchasing with us!
```

Here is the code:

```
lblmail.Text = "Your order is succesful! <br />" +
                            "------------------------------------------------ <br />" +
                            "Order ID : " + Session["OrderID"].ToString() + "< br />" +
                            "Order Date : " + Session["orderDate"].ToString() + "< br />" +
                            "Send To : " + Session["address"].ToString() + "< br />" +
                            "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + Session["state"].ToString() + "< br />" +
                            "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + Session["zipcode"].ToString() + "< br />" +
                            "Grand Total : " + Session["GrandTotal"].ToString() + "< br />" +
                            "< br />< br />Thank You for purchasing with us!" ;
```

Do note that I had enabled the HTML is the email body with this code:

```
 MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

 mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

What is the problem here? The code seems to be fine but the output is not what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add HTML insted of normal text

**Code**

```
var htmlContent ="<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h3><p>Your order is successful!</p></h3>
    <p>----------------------------------</p>
    <p>Order ID : Order20465230820207quiw</p>
    <p>Order Date : 8/30/2020</p>
    <p>Send To : 81,JALAN KENARI MERAH 8</p>
    <p>Grand Total : 499</p>
    <p>Thank You for purchasing with us!</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>";

using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
        {
            mm.Body = htmlContent;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        }
```

It's working fine with your mail functionality

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your HTML tags are written correctly "< br />" remove the spaces, with is this way you make sure that the server dose not send it as text.

```
< br /> To this <br/>
```